JPA Criteria query for postgres JSONB type having array items
I have the following JSONB column in my postgres table.



id
data




1
[{"sn": "sn1","mt":"mt1"}, {"sn": "sn2","mt":"mt2"}]


2
[{"sn": "sn3","mt":"mt3"}, {"sn": "sn4","mt":"mt4"}]



I would like to filter the rows where sn having value sn2.
I am able to achieve it with below postgres query,
select * from mytable where (exists(select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(data) obj where obj->>'sn'='sn2'));
Can we build the above query using JPA criteria builder API? There are other predicates as well in my query which I am able to build using criteria builder, however I am not able to build above exists predicate. Let me know if there are ways to combine above predicate as raw sql to existing predicates as well.
